# invalid conversion from 'signed char*' to 'char*' in sprintf

Tags: c++, char, printf, signed

Ok so I'm getting this error and I have no idea how to fix it:
invalid conversion from 'signed char*' to 'char*'

Dong (char*)ulStatsAsPercentage doesn't help.

I get this error in both sprintf statements, at the last argument in each, at ulStatsAsPercentage in the first sprintf statement, and at pxTaskStatusArray[ x ].ulRunTimeCounter in the second sprintf statement.

Here is my code:

```
  TaskStatus_t *pxTaskStatusArray;
  volatile UBaseType_t uxArraySize, x;
  unsigned long ulTotalRunTime, ulStatsAsPercentage;

  ulStatsAsPercentage =
              pxTaskStatusArray[ x ].ulRunTimeCounter / ulTotalRunTime;

  pxTaskStatusArray = (TaskStatus_t*)pvPortMalloc( uxArraySize * sizeof( TaskStatus_t ) );

   if( ulStatsAsPercentage > 0UL )
        {
           sprintf( pcWriteBuffer, "%s\t\t%lu\t\t%lu%%\r\n",
                             pxTaskStatusArray[ x ].pcTaskName,
                             pxTaskStatusArray[ x ].ulRunTimeCounter,
                             ulStatsAsPercentage );//error at this line
        }
        else
        {
           /* If the percentage is zero here then the task has
           consumed less than 1% of the total run time. */
           sprintf( pcWriteBuffer, "%s\t\t%lu\t\t<1%%\r\n",
                  pxTaskStatusArray[ x ].pcTaskName,
                  pxTaskStatusArray[ x ].ulRunTimeCounter );//error here too
        }
```

Here is the console showing the errors:

```
../L5_Application/main.cpp:181:60: error: invalid conversion from 'signed char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
                                  (char)ulStatsAsPercentage );

c:\users\alti\downloads\sjsu_dev\toolchain\arm-none-eabi\include\stdio.h:244:5: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'int sprintf(char*, const char*, ...)'
 int _EXFUN(sprintf, (char *__restrict, const char *__restrict, ...)
     ^
../L5_Application/main.cpp:181:60: warning: format '%lu' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument 5 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
                                  (char)ulStatsAsPercentage );
                                                            ^
../L5_Application/main.cpp:181:60: warning: format '%lu' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument 5 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
../L5_Application/main.cpp:189:74: error: invalid conversion from 'signed char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
                                  pxTaskStatusArray[ x ].ulRunTimeCounter );
                                                                          ^
c:\users\alti\downloads\sjsu_dev\toolchain\arm-none-eabi\include\stdio.h:244:5: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'int sprintf(char*, const char*, ...)'
 int _EXFUN(sprintf, (char *__restrict, const char *__restrict, ...)
     ^
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: On which line do you get the error? Can you please edit your question to mark it out with a comment? And then also please copy-paste the full and complete error output, including possible informational notes. And or course, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or at lease tell us the declarations of all involved variables.

Comment: How is `pcWriteBuffer` defined?

Comment: And casting `ulStatsAsPercentage` won't change anything, it's not what is being complained about (since the variable is an integer type).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i edited my question

Comment: @rici signed char *pcWriteBuffer

Comment: Why are you declaring it as `signed char`? Does your program logic require the elements of that buffer to be signed? That seems unlikely. Anyway, `sprintf` requires a `char*` argument, and `signed char` is nit the same type as `char`.

Comment: Well there you have it... Why did you declare `pcWriteBuffer` to be a `signed char *` instead of just plain `char *`?

Comment: oh right XD i'll try that out, Don't know why i didn't pay attention to that. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

The `char` type (as expected by `*printf("%s", ...)`) has implementation-defined signedness. It can be either signed or unsigned, it depends on compiler.

In your case, it is apparently unsigned per default. This means you can't treat `signed char` arrays as strings. Any `signed char` array or pointer either needs to have its type changed to `char` or `unsigned char` (best solution), or alternatively you can force an explicit conversion:

```
sprintf( (char*)pcWriteBuffer, ...  // quick & dirty fix
```

Comment: `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are three distinct types, even though the first one has the same representation as one of the other ones. (6.2.5/14 and following)

Comment: @rici Yes but you can always safely convert between all 3 types "in some implementation-defined manner".

Comment: You can convert between `char` and `signed char`. But there is no implicit conversion between `char*` and `signed char*` even if `char` and `signed char` have the same representation. So the fact that the compiler complains about the argument type says nothing about the signedness of `char`.

Comment: @rici I never said you could do it implicitly. Hence the cast in the answer.

Comment: that is what your second paragraph says. You deduce that `char` is unsigned (on what basis?) and then say that is why "you can't treat `signed char*` as a string." But `signed char*` cannot be used as an argument to a string function regardless of the signedness of `char`. You will get precisely the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are three distinct types. (§6.7.1/1 [basic.fundamental]). They must all have the same size and alignment, and `char` must be effectively identical to one of the other two, but they are still three separate types.

Because of integer conversion rules, it is possible to convert between the three character types without an explicit cast, so the following is perfectly valid:

```
int fn(char ch);

int main() {
  signed char c = 'A';
  return fn(c);
}
```

However, that doesn't mean you can convert between *pointers* to different character types.

```
int fn(char* ch);

int main(void) {
  signed char c[] = {'A', 0};
  return fn(c);
}
```

⇒ (with g++: clang++ says "No matching function for call to `fn`)

```
signed.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
signed.cc:5:14: error: invalid conversion from ‘signed char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
   return fn(c);
              ^
signed.cc:1:5: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int fn(char*)’
 int fn(char* ch);
     ^
```

Compiled with C rather than C++, this produces a warning (if `-Wall` is specified) rather than an error because C is more relaxed about pointer assignments of different types.

Note that this is not different from, for example, a function which expects `long*` being called with `long long*` on an architecture where both of those are 64-bit 2's complement arithmetic types with the same layout. For C++, different types are different types.